# XlaRuntimeError: FAILED_PRECONDITION: DNN library initialization failed

Tags: jax

## **Description**

The OUTPUT:

2023-07-31 01:53:45.016563: E external/xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:427] Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 8.5.0 but source was compiled with: 8.6.0. CuDNN library needs to have matching major version and equal or higher minor version. If using a binary install, upgrade your CuDNN library. If building from sources, make sure the library loaded at runtime is compatible with the version specified during compile configuration.

XlaRuntimeError Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 29

```
26 model = trainer.make_model(nmask)
28 lr_fn, opt = trainer.make_optimizer(steps_per_epoch=len(train_dl))
---> 29 state = trainer.create_train_state(jax.random.PRNGKey(0), model, opt)
30 state = checkpoints.restore_checkpoint(ckpt.parent, state)
```

File /mnt/data/miniconda/envs/energy_transformer_117/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jax/_src/random.py:137, in PRNGKey(seed)

```
134 if np.ndim(seed):
135 raise TypeError("PRNGKey accepts a scalar seed, but was given an array of"
136 f"shape {np.shape(seed)} != (). Use jax.vmap for batching")
--> 137 key = prng.seed_with_impl(impl, seed)
138 return _return_prng_keys(True, key)
```

File /mnt/data/miniconda/envs/energy_transformer_117/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jax/_src/prng.py:320, in seed_with_impl(impl, seed)

```
319 def seed_with_impl(impl: PRNGImpl, seed: Union[int, Array]) -> PRNGKeyArrayImpl:
--> 320 return random_seed(seed, impl=impl)
```

File /mnt/data/miniconda/envs/energy_transformer_117/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jax/_src/prng.py:734, in random_seed(seeds, impl)

```
732 else:
733 seeds_arr = jnp.asarray(seeds)
--> 734 return random_seed_p.bind(seeds_arr, impl=impl)
```

File /mnt/data/miniconda/envs/energy_transformer_117/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jax/_src/core.py:380, in Primitive.bind(self, *args, **params)

```
377 def bind(self, *args, **params):
378 assert (not config.jax_enable_checks or
379 all(isinstance(arg, Tracer) or valid_jaxtype(arg) for arg in args)), args
--> 380 return self.bind_with_trace(find_top_trace(args), args, params)
```

File /mnt/data/miniconda/envs/energy_transformer_117/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jax/_src/core.py:383, in Primitive.bind_with_trace(self, trace, args, params)

```
382 def bind_with_trace(self, trace, args, params):
--> 383 out = trace.process_primitive(self, map(trace.full_raise, args), params)
384 return map(full_lower, out) if self.multiple_results else full_lower(out)
```

File /mnt/data/miniconda/envs/energy_transformer_117/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jax/_src/core.py:790, in EvalTrace.process_primitive(self, primitive, tracers, params)

```
789 def process_primitive(self, primitive, tracers, params):
--> 790 return primitive.impl(*tracers, **params)
```

File /mnt/data/miniconda/envs/energy_transformer_117/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jax/_src/prng.py:746, in random_seed_impl(seeds, impl)

```
744 @random_seed_p.def_impl
745 def random_seed_impl(seeds, *, impl):
--> 746 base_arr = random_seed_impl_base(seeds, impl=impl)
747 return PRNGKeyArrayImpl(impl, base_arr)
```

File /mnt/data/miniconda/envs/energy_transformer_117/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jax/_src/prng.py:751, in random_seed_impl_base(seeds, impl)

```
749 def random_seed_impl_base(seeds, *, impl):
750 seed = iterated_vmap_unary(seeds.ndim, impl.seed)
--> 751 return seed(seeds)
```

File /mnt/data/miniconda/envs/energy_transformer_117/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jax/_src/prng.py:980, in threefry_seed(seed)

```
968 def threefry_seed(seed: typing.Array) -> typing.Array:
969 """Create a single raw threefry PRNG key from an integer seed.
970
971 Args:
(...)
978 first padding out with zeros).
979 """
--> 980 return _threefry_seed(seed)
```

[... skipping hidden 12 frame]
File /mnt/data/miniconda/envs/energy_transformer_117/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jax/_src/dispatch.py:463, in backend_compile(backend, module, options, host_callbacks)

```
458 return backend.compile(built_c, compile_options=options,
459 host_callbacks=host_callbacks)
460 # Some backends don't have host_callbacks option yet
461 # TODO(sharadmv): remove this fallback when all backends allow compile
462 # to take in host_callbacks
--> 463 return backend.compile(built_c, compile_options=options)`
```

XlaRuntimeError: FAILED_PRECONDITION: DNN library initialization failed. Look at the errors above for more details.

## **What jax/jaxlib version are you using?**

jax0.4.10, jaxlib0.4.10+cuda11.cudnn86

## **Which accelerator(s) are you using?**

GPU

## **Additional system info**

python3.11.4, Ubuntu22.04, cuda11.7,cudnn86

## **NVIDIA GPU info**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTSJe.png)

I hope to fix this error.

Answer (score 5):

The error message tells you what's wrong:

```
Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 8.5.0 but source was compiled with: 8.6.0.
If using a binary install, upgrade your CuDNN library. If building from
sources, make sure the library loaded at runtime is compatible with the
version specified during compile configuration.
```

You are using a `jaxlib` package that was compiled with CuDNN 8.6.0, but at runtime the system is finding CuDNN 8.5.0. In general, the way to fix this is to either install a jaxlib compiled with CuDNN 8.5.0, or to upgrade your system CuDNN to 8.6.0.

An easy way to achieve this is to reinstall jax in a fresh environment using the `cuda11_pip` or `cuda12_pip` options (see [installation instructions](https://github.com/google/jax#pip-installation-gpu-cuda-installed-via-pip-easier)), as this will ensure that your package versions match.

Comment: In case helpful, I used `nvidia-smi` to establish my cuda version as v12, then used: `pip install --upgrade "jax[cuda12_pip]" -f https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_cuda_releases.html`